# how can I troubleshoot these new php-pdf font errors?

Tags: php, pdf

Today our web server started throwing these errors when generating a pdf with php-pdf.  Path is wrong but the pdf still generates.  Unsure why this path issue started or how to fix it.  Also concerned that it just started seemingly on its own.

Warning: fopen(/tmp/cachedTimes-Roman.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/site/public_html/include/pdf-php/src/Cpdf.php on line 2039

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/site/public_html/include/pdf-php/src/Cpdf.php on line 2040

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/site/public_html/include/pdf-php/src/Cpdf.php on line 2041

Comment: You might get some inspiration there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings were caused by the script not being able to find the font files. The problem was solved by explicitly setting the tempPath.

```
$pdf->tempPath = '../include/pdf-php/src/fonts';
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the device where `/tmp` is may have run out of space, so that new files can not be created there.

`df -h` in console should get you started.

If you are the system administrator, even `rm -rf /tmp/*` might help, but may also have consequences if any files currently in use are stored there.

Comment: thanks thor, system admin confirmed it wasn't a space issue on the disc.